# R novice starting to copy the example from the doc - but does not work

Tags: r

I am a novice on R and try to follow the simple example to read a csv and convert it.
[example from the doc for import](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html#Imports)

I run R on ubuntu.
I have created the file in EXCEL and exported a csv, changed ";" by " " and moved it to the ubuntu and started R

```
zz <- read.csv("mr.csv", strip.white = TRUE)
```

result:

```
print(zz)
            Status.Age.V1.V2.V3.V4
1  P 23646 45190 50333 55166 56271
2 CC 26174 35535 38227 37911 41184
3 CC 27723 25691 25712 26144 26398
4 CC 27193 30949 29693 29754 30772
5 CC 24370 50542 51966 54341 54273
6 CC 28359 58591 58803 59435 61292
7 CC 25136 45801 45389 47197 47126
```

then

```
Fehler in `[.data.frame`(zz, gl(nrow(zz), 1, 4 * nrow(zz)), 1:2) : 
  nicht definierte Spalten gewählt
```

I appreciate any help what might be wrong.

Regards
Kallewirsch

Comment: You may read without the header i.er. `read.csv("mr.csv", skip = 1, header = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)` and then change the header.  If your `sep = " "`, you could use `read.table("mr.csv", skip = 1, header = FALSE)`

Comment: If you open `mr.csv` in a text editor, does it have commas between fields? Did you choose a different delimiter when saving to CSV. "CSV" stands for "comma separated values." It doesn't look like your input file has any commas. Not sure why you changed the semicolons to spaces. If that's the delimiter, then make sure to keep that in, and use `read.csv()` with `sep=";"`

Comment: mmh - result is then:

`print(zz)`

`                                V1
1  P 23646 45190 50333 55166 56271
2 CC 26174 35535 38227 37911 41184
3 CC 27723 25691 25712 26144 26398
4 CC 27193 30949 29693 29754 30772
5 CC 24370 50542 51966 54341 54273
6 CC 28359 58591 58803 59435 61292
7 CC 25136 45801 45389 47197 47126`

and this would indicate the documentation for starters is --- wrong?

Comment: this did the trick:

`zz <- read.csv("mr.csv", strip.white = TRUE, sep=";")`

yes, my EXCEL is GERMAN. So the export was "semicolon separated", rather than "comma separated".

Just for testing I will change the semicolons to commas to find out if the original command in the doc works - so I can follow the doc to learn.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenated header indicates that you are only getting one giant column for each row. I think what is happening is that European conventions for delimited text files are being used by your installation of Excel, so the file is not "CSV" but rather "semicolon separated. You should try this (after going back to the original exported file and not attempting any substitution of space for commas prior to the import:

```
zz <- read.delim("mr.csv")
```

`read.delim` also has the parameter dec="," for The European convention of decimal point as a comma so there's no need to do the any swapping of period for commas.

Comment: when doing so I get:
`Status.Age.V1.V2.V3.V4
1  P;23646;45190;50333;55166;56271
2 CC;26174;35535;38227;37911;41184
3 CC;27723;25691;25712;26144;26398
4 CC;27193;30949;29693;29754;30772
5 CC;24370;50542;51966;54341;54273
6 CC;28359;58591;58803;59435;61292
7 CC;25136;45801;45389;47197;47126`

Comment: As you can see, the separator is ";" but it appears that the header separator is different. Edit the header in the text file to also have semicolons separating values.